# Different Themes or Different code with if conditions?

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

We are selling different kind of products like Tshirts , Mobiles , Toys , Books , shoes..etc....

for each types there will be different type of product view pages.

so we have 2 options

1) **Create different Theme** to write code for different kind of products

2) **Same theme with different code** for different attribute sets, like below :

```
if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==20)
{  // code here // }
```

If we write too much code in view.phtml, is it going to effect on performance of product view page ?

which option is better for **performance** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance shouldn't be affected, but the code might become hard to read after a while.

I would create a new **Product View block** for the part you wish, and dynamically change the template according to the attribute set.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setTemplate('product/view/custom/....phtml');
    parent::_toHtml()
}
```